# F#, problems with IntelliSense and Office

Tags: f#, intellisense, office-interop

I'm trying to write some Office automation code and I cannot get IntelliSense help for the PIA Office types. The strange thing is that it works fine in C# and also in the Tutorial.vs2010 F# Solution with some of the same code.

I'm using VS10 and PIA for Office 14.

[image]

VS

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I forgot to include a reference to Office.dll. That appeared to fix the issue.

Comment: The tool tip displayed for the weird `<Note>` element usually says what assembly you're missing, so following that advice should fix the issue. (I'm not exactly sure why IntelliSense doesn't try to load it automatically though)

Comment: I was having the same problem. The confusing thing is that the hint displayed by intellisense is asking for the wrong assembly.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this later, but can't figure out where `office.dll` is, like I did. I faced the same Issue with F# 4.0, Office 2013, and VS Community 2015 Update 2.0

I typed this in the beginning of the file to get Intellisense working, no need to search for `office.dll` in your machine:

```
#r "office, Version = 15.0.0.0"
```

This is the same text it gives you with `<Note>`, but without the `Culture=neutral` and `PublicKey=w/e`. Seems to work flawlessly.

For context, this is how my file starts:

```
#r "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"
#r "office, Version = 15.0.0.0"


open System
open System.IO
open System.Reflection
open Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel


let app = ApplicationClass(Visible = true)

let sheet = app.Workbooks
               .Add()
               .Worksheets.[1] :?> _Worksheet
```